# Merging two stl containers without std::merge

Tags: c++, list, vector, merge, containers

I have to write a merging function that merges two stl containers without using std::merge. I wanted to use the implementation of std::merge, though.

```
template <typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator merge (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1, 
                      InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2, 
                      OutputIterator result) {
    while (true) {      
        if (first1==last1) 
            return std::copy(first2,last2,result);

        if (first2==last2) 
            return std::copy(first1,last1,result);

        *result++ = (*first2<*first1)? *first2++ : *first1++;
    }
}
```

I wanted to test it with this:

```
    std::vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(7);

std::list<int> l1;
l1.push_back(23);
l1.push_back(3);

std::vector<int> v2;
std::vector<int>::iterator first1 = v1.begin(), last1 = v1.end(), output = v2.end();
std::list<int>::iterator first2 = l1.begin(), last2 = l1.end();

merge<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::list<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>(first1, last1, first2, last2, output);
```

Why does this produce a run time error saying "Vector iterator not incrementable" ?

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, merging works but the output is unsorted

Comment: v2 is empty and hence you need to allocate memory for output list.

Comment: merge but not std:::merge, just lookup std::merge !? (somebody should slap a teacher)

Comment: @Dieter, it was my assumption that I'm not allowed to use std::merge as my task is "Implement a function that merges two STL Containers"

Comment: Your _inputs_ must be sorted before calling `merge`. The `l1` list in your example isn't sorted...

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for v2 to make the output result iterator dereferencable.

```
std::vector<int> v2( v1.size() + l1.size() );
```

And `output = v2.begin();`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write to, and beyond, `v2.end()`. This won't grow `v2`, it will just trample over invalid memory, giving undefined behaviour.

Either make `v2` large enough to write into:

```
std::vector<int> v2(v1.size() + l1.size());
auto output = v2.begin();
```

or use an insertion iterator

```
std::vector<int> v2;
auto output = std::back_inserter(v2);
```

By the way, there should be no need to specify the template arguments when calling `merge`; they can be inferred from the function arguments:

```
merge(first1, last1, first2, last2, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be rewritten the following way

```
std::vector<int> v1;
v1.reserve( 2 );
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(7);

std::list<int> l1;
l1.push_back(23);
l1.push_back(3);

std::vector<int> v2;
v2.reserve( v1.size() + l1.size() );

merge( v1.begin(), v1.end(), l1.begin(), l1.end(), std::back_inserter( v2 ) );
```